# how can i filter an array and return matches

Tags: php, arrays, strpos, array-filter

I want to return items that are "like" something else. 
I tried array_filter, but I can't use it correctly.

Here is what I tried. 
desired out put is

> one.php2000565, one.php999.php . 
>   Array([0] =>
>   one.php2000565[1]
>   => two.php[2] => three.php[3] => one.php999.php[4] => four.php)

```
$search_text = 'one.php';
array_filter($array, function($a) use ($search_text) {
    return ( strpos($a, $search_text) !== false );
});

Array([0] => one.php2000565[1] => two.php[2] => three.php[3] => one.php999.php[4] => four.php)

$search_text = 'one.php';
array_filter($array, function($a) use ($search_text) {
     return ( strpos($a, $search_text) !== false );
});
```

Comment: You need all the elements that contains one.php?

Comment: Your code works perfectly just get the `array_filter` value within a variable like as `$res = array_filter.....` and simply `print_r($res);`

Comment: yes thats what i want

Comment: hahahaha i dont know how i missed that. it works thanks

Comment: You're welcome. Glad it helped you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$res = array_filter($files, function($files) use ($search_program) {
    return ( strpos($files, $search_program) !== false );
});
print_r($res);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php):

```
$search_text = 'one.php';

array_filter($yourArray, function($el) use ($search_text) {
       return ( strpos($el, $search_text) !== false );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following solution :-

```
$example    = array([0] => one.php2000565[1] => two.php[2] => three.php[3] => one.php999.php[4] => four.php);
$searchword = 'one.php';
$matches    = array_filter($example, function($var) use ($searchword) { return preg_match("/\b$searchword\b/i", $var); });
```

It may help you.

Comment: It will list the element that contains the one.php

Comment: OPs code is working fine issue is OP is not getting the value within a variable [check this](https://3v4l.org/Hcmg0)

Answer (score 0):

You do not assign result of `array_filter`. PHP's [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)
returns the modified array. So just use:

```
$array = array_filter($array, 
   function($a) use ($search_text) {
       return ( 
           strpos($a, $search_text) !== false 
       );
   }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

As I've commented that OPs code is working fine with `array_filter` just need to assign the filtered value within a variable. But my solution is alternative to `array_filter` instead you can use `preg_grep` like as

```
$res = preg_grep("/$search_text/",$array);
print_r($res);
```